# How to serialize model class data as json

Tags: python, json, django, django-models

I want to add a view to my django application so that it showed data from table `Barati`.

**view.py**

```
from django.http.response import Http404, HttpResponse
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse

from trello.models import Sveti, Barati


def get_index(request):
   return TemplateResponse(request,'index.html')

def get_settings(request):
    if not request.is_ajax():
       raise Http404
    svetebi = Sveti.objects.all()
    res = '['
    for sveti in svetebi:
        res = res + '{"name": ' + sveti.name + ', "position": ' + str(sveti.position) + ', "cards": null},'
    res = res[:-1]
    res = res + ']'
    return HttpResponse(res)

    def add_sveti(request):
    if not request.is_ajax():
        raise Http404
    sveti = Sveti()
    sveti.name = request.GET['name']
    sveti.position = request.GET['position']
    sveti.save()
    return HttpResponse('{"success":true}')

def add_barati(request):
    if not request.is_ajax():
       raise Http404
    barati = Barati()
    barati.text = request.GET['text']
    barati.position = request.GET['position']
    barati.sveti_id = request.GET['sveti_id']
    barati.save()
    return HttpResponse('{"success":true}')
```

**models.py**

```
 from django.db import models


 class Sveti(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = 'sveti')
     position = models.IntegerField()

 class Barati(models.Model):
     sveti = models.ForeignKey(Sveti)
     text = models.CharField(max_length = 10000)
     position = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to add information about *Barati class* (from the models.py) to res in json format. But I can not go further from this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. Python comes with a [json module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

```
import json

dat = Sveti.objects.values("name", "position")
json_data = json.dumps(dat)
```

`Sveti.objects.values` creates a list of dictionaries of data containing selected fields and then you can serialize it to json with `dumps`
Or If you want to serialize all values you can use [django serializers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#serializing-django-objects)

```
from django.core import serializers
json_data = serializers.serialize("json", Sveti.objects.all())
```

You can use those methods to serialize Querysets that you want.

If you want to combine those data within the same json data you can use

```
json_data["sevni"] = serializers.serialize("json", Sveti.objects.all())
json_data["barati"] = serializers.serialize("json", Barati.objects.all())

>> print json_data

>> {"sveni": [{"id"............}, {.......}],
    "barati": [{"id"............}, {.......}] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Acoording to this django documantation ==> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/serialization/

```
#select all or use some filter, no matter
barati_json = serializers.serialize("json", Barati.objects.all())
```

and return the return_json. That's all..

**//edited:** concating the json contents by using a dict:

```
import json
return_dict = {
    'barati': barati_json,
    'some_other_integer_param1': 1,
    'some_other_param':"blabla"
}
json.dumps(return_dict)
```

Comment: return_json = serializers.serialize("json", Barati.objects.all())
res = res + '{"name": ' + sveti.name + ', "position": ' + str(sveti.position) + ', "cards":' + return_json+ '},'

Comment: so i can write something like this?

Comment: yes but u must collect all off your return parameters in a dict and dump dict to json. I edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

You are constructing the JSON string by hand, which is unusual and unnecessary. I would recommend this code to return all instances of both models in JSON:

```
import json

def get_settings(request):
    if not request.is_ajax():
       raise Http404
    sveti_all = list(Sveti.objects.all())
    barati_all = list(Barati.objects.all())
    return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize('json', sveti_all + barati_all))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've recently had to serialize some data to json myself and here's what I found useful.

In models.py:

```
class Person(models.Model):
      id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
      name = models.CharField()
      address = models.CharField()
      extra1 = models.CharField()
      extra2 = models.CharField()

def as_my_person(self):
     return {
        "id":self.id,
        "name":self.name,
        "address":self.address

     }
```

In the example above, I have a model that has 5 field and I only want my json data to have id, name and address.

In my views.py:

```
def person_view(request):
    data = Person.objects.filter(name__contains='john')
    dictionaries = [obj.as_my_person() for obj in data]
    serialized_data = simplejson.dumps(dictionaries)
    return HttpResponse(serialized_data, mimetype='application/json')
```

The code above should return a json string of all person with the name like 'john'.

```
[{ "id":1,"name":"john smith","address":"123 Main" }, { "id": 5, "name":"john doe", "address":"123 state" }]
```

I've found that's a quick and simple way to format and return JSON data to any front end UI framework like Kendo.

Hope it helps.